$S$-matrix element in QED (1st Order)
In my QFT lecture we considered the Møller scattering, and the lecturer said that the first-order term gives zero. I am trying to understand why it is zero. Perhaps one can argue that, but I am simply calculating the matrix element, because along the way I encounter different problems and I learn new rules, etc.
The vector field can be written as:
$$A_\mu=A_\mu^{+} + A_\mu^{-}$$
$$A_\mu^{+}=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}
\sum_\lambda c_\lambda\epsilon_\mu^{(\lambda)}(\vec k)e^{-ikx}$$
$$A_\mu^{-}=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}
\sum_\lambda c_\lambda^\dagger\epsilon_\mu^{*(\lambda)}(\vec k)e^{ikx}$$
The spinor fields are similarly:
$$\psi =\psi^{(-)} +\psi^{(+)}$$
$$\bar{\psi}=\bar {\psi}^{(+)}+ {\psi}^{(-)}$$
$$\psi^{(-)}=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}
\sum_se^{ikx}v_s(\vec k)b_s^\dagger(\vec k)$$
$$\psi^{(+)}=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}
\sum_se^{-ikx}u_s(\vec k)a_s(\vec k)$$
$\bar {\psi}^{(+)}=\int\sum_se^{-ikx}\bar{v}_s(\vec k)b_s(\vec k)\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}$
$\bar {\psi}^{(-)}=\int\sum_se^{ikx}\bar{U}_s(\vec k)a_s^\dagger(\vec k)\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^32\omega_k}$
Regarding $\langle f|S|i \rangle$ one has:
$$\langle f|S|i \rangle=\langle f|i\rangle + i \langle f|\int T\mathcal{L}_Id^4x|i\rangle + \frac{i^2e^2}{2}\langle f|\int T(\mathcal{L}_I(x)\mathcal{L}_I(y))d^4xd^y|i\rangle+...$$
where $\mathcal{L}_I=\bar {\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu$.
It was said that the first order term gives zero.
$T\mathcal{L}_I=T(\bar {\psi} \psi A_\mu)$ (ignore $\gamma^\mu$ as it plays no role here)
Wick theorem tells us:
$T(\bar {\psi} \psi A_\mu)= N \{\bar {\psi} \psi A_\mu + [\bar \psi,\psi]A_\mu + [\bar \psi,A_\mu]\psi + \bar \psi [\psi,A_\mu] \}$
Contraction between fields of different types is zero. This means that only the first two terms survive.
We have:
$|i\rangle=a^\dagger(\vec p_1)a^\dagger(\vec p_2)|0\rangle$
$|f\rangle=a^\dagger(\vec p_3)a^\dagger(\vec p_4)|0\rangle$
The relevant matrix element is:
$$\langle 0|a_3a_4 N \{\bar {\psi} \psi A_\mu + [\bar \psi,\psi]A_\mu \}a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger|0\rangle=$$
$$\langle 0|a_3a_4 N \{\bar {\psi} \psi A_\mu\} a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger|0\rangle + \langle 0|a_3a_4 N \{ [\bar \psi,\psi]A_\mu\} a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger|0\rangle=$$
Then one writes all the field operators via the corresponding annihilating and creating terms etc. So it is a length calculation, if the steps are correct.
So how is it possible to assert that the first order term is zero, without this length calculation?
Edit:
Are the steps that I undertake  along the way correct?

The interaction $\mathcal{L}_{I}$ has just one power of the electromagnetic field.  So your Fourier expansion of $A^{\mu}$ only contains terms with a single photon creation or annihilation operator.  The first order matrix element can thus only be nonzero for processes that change photon number by one.  Møller scattering is not such a process; it has no change in the number of photons between the incoming and outgoing states.
There is a further argument (basically what is outlined in the question, just stated more concisely) that there not enough Dirac operators in $\mathcal{L}_{I}$ either.  There are only two fermion creation or annihilation operators, not enough to convert the initial two-particle state into the different two-particle final state.

If $\bar \psi$ and $\psi$ can be Fourier expand, you'd have 4 combinations of two types of ladder operators. If I understand correctly because we have 2 electrons initially and 2 in the final state, you'd need to have an expression that contains 2 annihilation operators, to annihilate the initial state electrons and 2 creation one, to create the 2 final state electrons? Is this description correct?

@imbAF That's correct, and I fixed my "photon operator" mistake to "photon number."
